# How to check when an element changes its state from enable to disable in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I have a view of items. There are total 29 pages and in one page there are 20 items are displayed. I'm trying to get the count of total items (including all pages) via selenium.

Here is the HTML for the first page :

```
<div class="pagination pagination-toolbar clearfix">


            <nav role="navigation" aria-label="Pagination">
            <ul class="pagination-list">
                    <li class="disabled">
    <span >
        <span class="icon-backward icon-first" aria-hidden="true"></span>   </span>
    </li>
    <li class="disabled">
    <span >
        <span class="icon-step-backward icon-previous" aria-hidden="true"></span>   </span>
    </li>
                                        <li class="active">
    <span aria-current="true" aria-label="Page 1">
        1   </span>
    </li>
                                        <li class="hidden-phone">
        <a aria-label="Go to page 2"   href="#" onclick="document.adminForm.limitstart.value=20; submitform();return false;">
            2       </a>
    </li>
                                        <li class="hidden-phone">
        <a aria-label="Go to page 3"   href="#" onclick="document.adminForm.limitstart.value=40; submitform();return false;">
            3       </a>
    </li>
                                        <li class="hidden-phone">
        <a aria-label="Go to page 4"   href="#" onclick="document.adminForm.limitstart.value=60; submitform();return false;">
            4       </a>
    </li>
                                        <li class="hidden-phone">
        <a aria-label="Go to page 5"   href="#" onclick="document.adminForm.limitstart.value=80; submitform();return false;">
            5       </a>
    </li>
                                        <li class="hidden-phone">
        <a aria-label="Go to page 6"   href="#" onclick="document.adminForm.limitstart.value=100; submitform();return false;">
            6       </a>
    </li>
                                        <li class="hidden-phone">
        <a aria-label="Go to page 7"   href="#" onclick="document.adminForm.limitstart.value=120; submitform();return false;">
            7       </a>
    </li>
                                        <li class="hidden-phone">
        <a aria-label="Go to page 8"   href="#" onclick="document.adminForm.limitstart.value=140; submitform();return false;">
            8       </a>
    </li>
                                        <li class="hidden-phone">
        <a aria-label="Go to page 9"   href="#" onclick="document.adminForm.limitstart.value=160; submitform();return false;">
            9       </a>
    </li>
                                        <li class="hidden-phone">
        <a aria-label="Go to page 10"   href="#" onclick="document.adminForm.limitstart.value=180; submitform();return false;">
            10      </a>
    </li>
                                    <li>
        <a aria-label="Go to next page" class="hasTooltip"  title="Next"  href="#" onclick="document.adminForm.limitstart.value=20; submitform();return false;">
            <span class="icon-step-forward icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a aria-label="Go to end page" class="hasTooltip"  title="End (Page 29 of 29)"  href="#" onclick="document.adminForm.limitstart.value=560; submitform();return false;">
            <span class="icon-forward icon-last" aria-hidden="true"></span>     </a>
    </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

            <input type="hidden" name="limitstart" value="0" />

</div>
```

Here is the HTML of last page:

```
<div class="pagination pagination-toolbar clearfix">


            <nav role="navigation" aria-label="Pagination">
            <ul class="pagination-list">
                    <li>
        <a aria-label="Go to start page" class="hasTooltip"  title="Start (Page 1 of 29)"  href="#" onclick="document.adminForm.limitstart.value=0; submitform();return false;">
            <span class="icon-backward icon-first" aria-hidden="true"></span>       </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a aria-label="Go to previous page" class="hasTooltip"  title="Previous"  href="#" onclick="document.adminForm.limitstart.value=540; submitform();return false;">
            <span class="icon-step-backward icon-previous" aria-hidden="true"></span>       </a>
    </li>
                                        <li class="hidden-phone">
        <a aria-label="Go to page 20"   href="#" onclick="document.adminForm.limitstart.value=380; submitform();return false;">
            20      </a>
    </li>
                                        <li class="hidden-phone">
        <a aria-label="Go to page 21"   href="#" onclick="document.adminForm.limitstart.value=400; submitform();return false;">
            21      </a>
    </li>
                                        <li class="hidden-phone">
        <a aria-label="Go to page 22"   href="#" onclick="document.adminForm.limitstart.value=420; submitform();return false;">
            22      </a>
    </li>
                                        <li class="hidden-phone">
        <a aria-label="Go to page 23"   href="#" onclick="document.adminForm.limitstart.value=440; submitform();return false;">
            23      </a>
    </li>
                                        <li class="hidden-phone">
        <a aria-label="Go to page 24"   href="#" onclick="document.adminForm.limitstart.value=460; submitform();return false;">
            24      </a>
    </li>
                                        <li class="hidden-phone">
        <a aria-label="Go to page 25"   href="#" onclick="document.adminForm.limitstart.value=480; submitform();return false;">
            25      </a>
    </li>
                                        <li class="hidden-phone">
        <a aria-label="Go to page 26"   href="#" onclick="document.adminForm.limitstart.value=500; submitform();return false;">
            26      </a>
    </li>
                                        <li class="hidden-phone">
        <a aria-label="Go to page 27"   href="#" onclick="document.adminForm.limitstart.value=520; submitform();return false;">
            27      </a>
    </li>
                                        <li class="hidden-phone">
        <a aria-label="Go to page 28"   href="#" onclick="document.adminForm.limitstart.value=540; submitform();return false;">
            28      </a>
    </li>
                                        <li class="active">
    <span aria-current="true" aria-label="Page 29">
        29  </span>
    </li>
                                    <li class="disabled">
    <span >
        <span class="icon-step-forward icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>    </span>
    </li>
    <li class="disabled">
    <span >
        <span class="icon-forward icon-last" aria-hidden="true"></span> </span>
    </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

            <input type="hidden" name="limitstart" value="560" />

</div>
```

I'm able to reach till the last page. But on reaching the last page, it continues to find the element to click which is no longer active.

Here is my Selenium Code:

```
WebElement pag = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[not(contains(@class, 'disabled'))]/a/span[(contains(@class, 'icon-next'))]"));
        while(pag!= null)
        {
            ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
            driver.findElement(By.className("icon-next")).click();
            List <WebElement> itemlist = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='tjlms-tbl']/table/tbody/tr"));
            total = total + itemlist.size();
        }
```

The loop is getting infinite. How can I stop once the last page is reached and the state of element changes to disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, the Next Page button is enabled /disabled based on the below section in HTML and If the button is disabled, then `class='disabled'` is added in HTML. So, we can iterate the while loop until the above disabled element found . Please check the below solution code

**First Page HTML:**

```
    <li class="hidden-phone">
        <a aria-label="Go to page 10"   href="#" onclick="document.adminForm.limitstart.value=180; submitform();return false;">
    10      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a aria-label="Go to next page" class="hasTooltip"  title="Next"  href="#" onclick="document.adminForm.limitstart.value=20; submitform();return false;">
            <span class="icon-step-forward icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a aria-label="Go to end page" class="hasTooltip"  title="End (Page 29 of 29)"  href="#" onclick="document.adminForm.limitstart.value=560; submitform();return false;">
            <span class="icon-forward icon-last" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Last Page HTML:**

```
        <li class="active">
            <span aria-current="true" aria-label="Page 29">
    29  </span>
        </li>
        <li class="disabled">
            <span >
                <span class="icon-step-forward icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li class="disabled">
            <span >
                <span class="icon-forward icon-last" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<input type="hidden" name="limitstart" value="560" />
```

**Solution Code:**

```
    List <WebElement> fistPagelist = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='tjlms-tbl']/table/tbody/tr"));
    total = fistPagelist .size();
boolean hasNextPage=true;

    while(hasNextPage)
    {
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
        List <WebElement> disabledButtonList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[@class='disabled']//span[@class='icon-forward icon-last']"));

        //If the page is lastpage, then only above disabledButtonList webElement will be found and it's size will be 1. Otherwise, it's size will be 0.

        if(disabledButtonList.size()==0){
            driver.findElement(By.className("icon-next")).click();
            List <WebElement> itemlist = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='tjlms-tbl']/table/tbody/tr"));
            total = total + itemlist.size();
            //Inorder to iterate the while loop, hasNextPage flag value is set it as true
            hasNextPage=true;           
        }
        else{
             List <WebElement> itemlist = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='tjlms-tbl']/table/tbody/tr"));
             total = total + itemlist.size();
            //If the LastPage found, then we need to stop the while loop and hence hasNextPage flag value is set it as false;
            hasNextPage=false;  
            System.out.println("You have reached the last page");
        }           
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Subburaj! This worked :). But I have two questions. 1. The execution time is more in this case, is there way we can minimise the execution time?. 2. In Last Page HTML markup, you can see that the limit start value is 560. But when I execute this code, it gives me 545 only. There are 20 items per page. Loop goes well till 27 Page I got value as 540 but for some reason its skipping one page not sure why. Can you please advise. Thanks a bunch in advance!

Comment: #1, If you want to navigate all the pages one by one and need to find the record count, then execution takes some time.Since, we need to find the element for each page and it needs to be executed unitl last page. Alternatively, If there is some option to display all the records in a single page or increase the page limit count from 20 to 50 /100, then it will reduce the execution time.  #2, Whether you are getting the record count manually? I have added the count details in else part as well. So, that it can include the last page record count as well.

Comment: Do you have any other option to display the total no of Record(Above the pagination) in your Application without doing the page navigation?

Comment: I have dashboard where total no. of Records gets displayed. But by iterating through each page I'm just verifying that the the dashboard count is correct w.r.t. to actual available records. I have checked for the not getting the actual count while iterating via while loop you suggested - I found that loop is iterating backwards (prints data in reverse) and it skips few rows and starts from one particular record from the middle of the page.

Comment: Actually, here we are calculating the size after clicking the next page.so, the first page record count will be missed. Please add the count calculation before the while loop as well. (edited answer)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Subbraj.

Comment: Also, is there a way to exclude the duplicate elements (if any) from the total count, the above code is working but its getting all the elements including the duplicate entries as well. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How will you differentiate the duplicate?If you are meant some name is duplicate, then we can find the unique record count using set/map.

Comment: Yeah! I mean the name. for example one user is enrolled to multiple events, I need to get the count of enrolled user only, in this case count should be 1. Sure, Thanks! I will try using Set. Hope it will work. Thanks again!

Comment: I tried converting List to Set to get the unique values but no luck. What's the best way to convert the List to Set (for the above scenario). Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to iterate all the elements one by one and then need to add it in Set/Hashmap. Because, we are simply taking the total count using findElement s methods from single page.If we are parsing each element, then only we will come to know about duplicate entries. one more for loop needs to be added.If you are having some 500 Records, then 500 times loop needs to be executed inorder to add it in Set/HashMap.

Comment: I would suggest you to create new question and I will help you on that.

Comment: Thanks! I have created new question. Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51158891/selenium-how-to-skip-the-record-from-the-set-after-the-its-first-occurrence

Answer (score 1):

You can check if element is `enabled` like this:

```
if (element.isEnabled()) {
   // do stuff
}else {
   break;
}
```

in your code it could be like this:

```
WebElement pag = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[not(contains(@class, 'disabled'))]/a/span[(contains(@class, 'icon-next'))]"));
while(pag!= null)
{
  ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
  WebElement next = driver.findElement(By.className("icon-next"));
  if (next.isEnabled()){
    next.click(); // click only if enabled
    List <WebElement> itemlist = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='tjlms-tbl']/table/tbody/tr"));
    total = total + itemlist.size();
  }else { // break the loop if not enabled
    System.out.println("You have reached the last page");
    break;
  }
}
```

or you can try also this way:

```
List<WebElement> pag = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[not(contains(@class, 'disabled'))]/a/span[(contains(@class, 'icon-next'))]"));
while(pag.size() > 0)
{
  pag = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[not(contains(@class, 'disabled'))]/a/span[(contains(@class, 'icon-next'))]"));
  ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
  driver.findElement(By.className("icon-next")).click();
  List <WebElement> itemlist = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='tjlms-tbl']/table/tbody/tr"));
  total = total + itemlist.size();
}
```

Here every time you locate the list of elements and if the list `size` becomes `0`, then you have reached the last page.

Comment: Thanks @Andrei! It helped to some extent but next.isEnabled for the next button isn't work in my case not sure why!