# Selenium - How to skip the record from the Set after the its first occurrence

Tags: java, selenium

I have an application view, where there are list of items. There are say 10 pages with 200 records, 20 records per page. I wish to have the unqiue user count assigned. From the below code I'am able to get the unique records per page. But I wish to get unique user entry throughout the records. So for example while execution if user "Jack" is found, so if the same user is found in later pages I want it to get skipped. Thanks in advance!

Script:

```
List<WebElement> efirstpagecount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='usersList']/tbody/tr/td[3]"));
Set<String> uniqueUsers = efirstpagecount.stream().map(WebElement::getText).map(String::trim).distinct().collect(Collectors.toSet());   
System.out.println("First page count: "+uniqueUsers.size());
```

Comment: Do you want to have one set for all users or set for every page?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think one set for all the users will do. My aim is to get the unique list of users. Having one Set for all  - will affect the performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge your sets like this:

```
set1.addAll(set2);
```

It will add distinct all elements from set2 to a set1.
The code sample:

```
List<WebElement> efirstpagecount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='usersList']/tbody/tr/td[3]"));
Set<String> uniqueUsers = efirstpagecount.stream().map(WebElement::getText).map(String::trim).distinct().collect(Collectors.toSet());   
System.out.println("First page count: "+uniqueUsers.size());

List<WebElement> esecondpagecount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='usersList']/tbody/tr/td[3]"));
Set<String> uniqueUsers2 = esecondpagecount.stream().map(WebElement::getText).map(String::trim).distinct().collect(Collectors.toSet());
uniqueUsers.addAll(uniqueUsers2); // merge two sets
System.out.println("First and second page count: "+uniqueUsers.size());
```

or this:

```
Set<String> allUsers = new HashSet();
while(true){
  List<WebElement> users = driver.findElements(By.xpath("xpath"));
  allUsers.addAll(users.stream().map(WebElement::getText).map(String::trim).distinct().collect(Collectors.toSet()));
  // move to next page if exists, else break loop
}
System.out.println("All pages count: " + allUsers.size());
```

PS performance of `addAll()` is O(N):

```
// implementation of addAll() method
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    boolean modified = false;
    for (E e : c)
        if (add(e))
            modified = true;
    return modified;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrei. It worked. Though I'm not getting the exact expected count, but I got the idea now how to go with it. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
List<WebElement> efirstpagecount =  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='usersList']/tbody/tr/td[3]"));
for(WebElement ele : efirstpagecount){
        set.add(ele.getText()); 
        }
```

This way Set will not have duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the value as below.

For Example, In the first Page you will get matched list of users.So,add the same in one of set.

```
HashSet<String> set=new HashSet<>();

List<WebElement> efirstpagecount  = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='usersList']/tbody/tr/td[3]"))

    for(WebElement element :efirstpagecount ){
        set.add(element.getText());
    }
```

After doing each pagination then add the below condition as well, then it will keep on adding the value in set Object and finally you can get the

```
while(hasNextPage)
    {
    ------------------
    ------------------
            List<WebElement> userList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='usersList']/tbody/tr/td[3]"))

            for(WebElement element :userList){
                set.add(element.getText());
            }

    ------------------

    }
```

Finally, after navigating all the pages, you will have unique set value and you can get the unique count and unique value as below

```
    System.out.println("Unique User No :"+set.size());

    for(String user: set){
        System.out.println(user);
    }
```